# python paramiko SSHException: Channel closed

Tags: python, paramiko

Im trying to establish a sftp connection to remote ubuntu machine.I was able to establish ssh connection.but it throws me an exception at open_sftp()

```
import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(hostname=hostname,port=port,username=username,password=password)
sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
```

paramiko.SSHException: Channel closed

can anyone help me.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last time I used SFTP with Paramiko, I also had some issues. I searched a bit on the web and i found this tool : https://github.com/jbardin/scp.py

To use it :

```
from scp import SCPClient
import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(hostname=hostname,port=port,username=username,password=password)

scpclient = SCPClient(ssh.get_transport(), socket_timeout=15.0)
scpclient.put("my_local_path", "my_remote_path")
```

Comment: Thanks FunkySayu. It is working fine now. But what is the problem there in open_sftp() because here i want to use an extra python package

Comment: Maybe it could help ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10345594/paramiko-sshexception-channel-closed
There're many topic on internet about it, and it looks like a bug. Which extra python package ?

Comment: Thanks alot. @FunkySayu I spend like multiple hours to get this fixed. Finally your solution works.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

uncomment this line:

```
# Subsystem     sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

On remote operating systems other than Ubuntu, the commented line listed in [yong's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47922294/9931644) may not exist. In this case, you may be able to fix the problem by adding the line to the file with the path modified to point to the correct location for your remote system's `sftp-server`.

On QNX, I was able to resolve this issue by modifying the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file and adding in the line:

```
Subsystem     sftp    /usr/libexec/sftp-server
```

Although the formatting for that line seemed out of place compared to the rest of the file, it still proved to be a successful solution as I was able to successfully open an SFTP client from an SSH client object without generating an SSHException.